# Coco creator using with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cocoscreator

It's not working code autocompletion and definition in vs code .
I have finished to create creator.d.ts and jsconfig.json.

Answer (score 2):

I have some expected solutions..

1. Create Project with Typescript
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pxyc.png)
2. Configuration in Editor
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLz1K.png)

   - (Developer -> VS Code Workflow -> Add Typescript Config)
   - (Developer -> VS Code Workflow -> Compile Task)
3. Install TsLint in VSCode (Cmd + Shift + P -> "install Extensions" -> TsLint)